# Почему после запуска js кода не срабатывает медиа-запроc?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, media-queries

Есть код после запуска которого не срабатывает медиа-запрос.

```
 document.querySelector('.search').onclick = function() {
  var clientWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
  var mnu = document.querySelector('.mnu');
  var sandwichMnu = document.querySelector('.sandwich-mnu');
  var searchBtn = document.querySelector('.search-button');

  if(searchBtn.classList.contains('search-button-active')) {

    searchBtn.classList.remove('search-button-active');
    if(clientWidth > 1620) {
      mnu.style.display = 'flex';
      sandwichMnu.style.display = 'none';
    }

  } else {

    if(clientWidth <= 1850) {
      mnu.style.display = 'none';
      sandwichMnu.style.display = 'flex';
    }

    searchBtn.classList.add('search-button-active');

  }
}
```

А вот сам медиа-запрос:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1620px) 
.head-navigation .mnu
    display: none

.sandwich-mnu
    display: flex
```

Не могу понять причину. Может дело в приоритетах?

Comment: потому что `JS` додает на в файл css стиле а для самого элементу, лутше не добавлять стили а класы для этих элементов который содержат нужные стили. О приоритетах - https://webref.ru/course/css-basics/priority

Comment: Да, в приоритетах. Достаточно было посмотреть на сгенерированные стили до и после срабатывания скрипта. Скрипт создает инлайн-стили, имеющие высший приоритет. Или стилям в медиаквери добавляйте !important (лучше не делайте так) или вместо инлайн-стилей, как написали выше, добавляйте CSS-классы.